# JavaScript forEach: mutate elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to use forEach on an array. Since forEach is a mutator, it should mutate the values in the original array, but it's not. What's the issue here?

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]; //simple array declaration

array.forEach((ele) => ele * 2); //using forEach to double each element in "array"

console.log(array); //logs [1,2,3,4] instead of [1,4,6,8]
```

What's going on here?

Comment: What gave you the idea that `forEach()` is a mutator?

Comment: `array.forEach((ele, i) => (array[i] *= 2));`

Comment: I think you're looking for [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Reyno Maybe, but `map()` also doesn't mutate the input array.

Comment: Yes you're correct, should have specified that. But [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will help with OP's use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `forEach` does not mutate the original array.

You can achieve what you are looking for by giving a second parameter of `index`, then updating the values of the original array.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array.forEach((ele, index) => array[index] = ele * 2);

console.log(array);
```

documentation for [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback has second and third optional parameters that you can use to access and mutate each element:

> index [Optional]:
> The index of element in the array.

> array [Optional]:
> The array forEach() was called upon.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

array.forEach((_, index, arr) => arr[index] *= 2);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: The second example is providing a `this` value, but the third parameter passed to the callback will be the array it was called on which is a more direct way to access the array than assigning `this`. `array.forEach(function(ele, index, arr) { arr[index] *= 2 });`